# Two macbooks next to each other have vastly different internet speed while on the *same* wifi

Tags: wifi

I have next to each other 2 Macbooks (slightly diff models and different amounts of RAM) - they both are on the same wifi

One has great internet speed: [19Mbps upload & download](https://www.speedtest.net/result/13576597530)

The other one is struggling: [0.80Mbps download speed & 1.05Mbps upload speed](https://www.speedtest.net/result/13576609035)

The above tests were done in the Chrome browser.

To make sure it isn't browser related I downloaded the Speedtest app on the second macbook. The result was not much better: [1.5Mbps download & 5.15Mpbs upload speed](https://www.speedtest.net/result/d/459920824)

It is obvious that the second Macbook has issues related to itself rather than the wifi. How to diagnose these?

Comment: Does it only happen when you use a specific browser, like chrome for example, or all the time?

Comment: @OrbitalBombardment Thanks for your question! I edited the post to add the info about the internet speed test I did via an app (rather than a browser).

Answer (score 0):

Can you open developer tools and check in the `Network` tab if you are throttling the network? The value should be `No throttling`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - there is no throttling. As mentioned, I did a test not just in the Chrome browser but also using Speedtest's app - which showed low internet speed, too. So it can't be the throttling in Chrome.